# How to fix Query parameters lost after reloading in Nextjs Router when keeping URL clean?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I'm trying to pass some data over router.push to a `[roomid] page (src/pages/editor/[roomid].tsx)` in Next.js using the following syntax, but want the URL to remain clear, as the user can just edit their username in the URL otherwise.

On the first load, `router.query` does persist `username` (passed in query). However, **after reloading**, username doesn't persist.

JoinRoom.tsx: two fields (username and roomid). when submit is pressed, user is directed to /[roomid]:

```
router.push({
    pathname: `/editor/${roomId}`,
    query: { username: username, }
}, `/editor/${roomId}`,
```

then in [roomid].tsx:

```
const router = useRouter();
const { roomid, username } = router.query;
```

after reloading, `username` comes **undefined**.

I've tried using the following in [roomid].tsx , but no luck, username still doesnt persist after reloading.

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady) {
        console.log(router.query);
        setUsername(router.query.username as string);
    }
}, [router.isReady]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const MyPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { roomid } = router.query;
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem('username')) {
      setUsername(localStorage.getItem('username') as string);
    } else if (router.query.username) {
      setUsername(router.query.username as string);
      localStorage.setItem('username', router.query.username as string);
    }
  }, [router.query.username, router]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Room ID: {roomid}</h1>
      <p>Username: {username}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyPage;
```

Comment: tried, no luck, username comes undefined after reload

Comment: update it with localStorage

Comment: ya, I'm using sessionStorage for username for the time being.